# FabricJS and AngularJS – copy and paste object with custom attribute

Tags: angularjs, fabricjs

I'm using some custom attributes while I'm creating my objects. For example in this case "name" and "icon":

```
$scope.addRoundRect = function () {
    var coord = getRandomLeftTop();

    var roundrect = (new fabric.Rect({
        left: coord.left,
        top: coord.top,
        fill: '#' + getRandomColor(),
        width: 250,
        height: 250,
        opacity: 1,
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        angle: 0,
        rx: 10,
        ry: 10,
        strokeWidth: 0,
        name: "Rounded Rectangle",
        icon: "crop-square"
    }));
    canvas.add(roundrect).setActiveObject(roundrect);
};
```

This is my copy/paste function. As you can see I have already tried to paste the relevant attributes – bu I think that they are simply not cloned with the object:

```
function copy() {
    canvas.getActiveObject().clone(function (cloned) {
        _clipboard = cloned;
    });
}

function paste() {
    _clipboard.clone(function (clonedObj) {
        canvas.discardActiveObject();
        clonedObj.set({
            left: clonedObj.left + 10,
            top: clonedObj.top + 10,
            evented: true,
            name: clonedObj.name,
            icon: clonedObj.icon,
        });
        if (clonedObj.type === 'activeSelection') {
            clonedObj.canvas = canvas;
            clonedObj.forEachObject(function (obj) {
                canvas.add(obj);
            });
            clonedObj.setCoords();
        } else {
            canvas.add(clonedObj);
        }
        canvas.setActiveObject(clonedObj);
        canvas.requestRenderAll();
    });
```

To make it short: is there a way to clone and paste also this attributes without having to modify the source (ie. impleneting a full fledged custom attribute in the JSO serialization)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var roundrect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 30,
  fill: 'blue',
  width: 250,
  height: 250,
  opacity: 1,
  scaleX: 1,
  scaleY: 1,
  angle: 0,
  rx: 10,
  ry: 10,
  strokeWidth: 0,
  name: "Rounded Rectangle",
  icon: "crop-square"
});
canvas.add(roundrect).setActiveObject(roundrect);

var customProperties = 'name icon'.split(' ');

function copy() {
  canvas.getActiveObject().clone(function(cloned) {
    console.log(cloned);
    _clipboard = cloned;
  }, customProperties);
}

function paste() {
  // clone again, so you can do multiple copies.
  _clipboard.clone(function(clonedObj) {
    canvas.discardActiveObject();
    clonedObj.set({
      left: clonedObj.left + 10,
      top: clonedObj.top + 10,
      evented: true,
    });
    if (clonedObj.type === 'activeSelection') {
        // active selection needs a reference to the canvas.
        clonedObj.canvas = canvas;
        clonedObj.forEachObject(function (obj) {
            canvas.add(obj);
        });
        // this should solve the unselectability
        clonedObj.setCoords();
    } else {
       canvas.add(clonedObj);
    }
    canvas.setActiveObject(clonedObj);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
    console.log(clonedObj);
    
    _clipboard = clonedObj;
 },customProperties);
}
```

```css
canvas {
 border: blue dotted 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='copy()'>copy</button>
<button onclick='paste()'>paste</button><br>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

[object.clone](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#clone) accepts callback function and any additional property you want to include as another parameter. You can send your name and icon as properties to include.

And in paste you no need to clone that object if you are doing so, make sure there also send you are including your additional properties.

Comment: – thanks again! But using this in my controller (copy pasted you code there) I am getting "controller.js:267 Uncaught ReferenceError: customProperties is not defined" while copy and "Uncaught ReferenceError: _clipboard is not defined" while pasting the object.

Comment: – thanks again! But using this in my controller (copy pasted you code there) I am getting "controller.js:267 Uncaught ReferenceError: customProperties is not defined" while copy and "Uncaught ReferenceError: _clipboard is not defined" while pasting the object.

Regarding the clone in the paste function. See this fiddle that we worked out with @asturur and (but now I am really absolutely unsure where I should add the "customProperties" in that context...

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wta4pdpz/14/

Comment: – sorry mate, I'm a bit overworked! I just missed a line of code... ;-( Copy and paste is working now. have to check now multiple copies also (the solution in our fiddle).... THANKS!!!

Comment: @Druga – made some testings now. Your version is working well. The only thing is that it don't allows to paste the copied object multiple times. This is what the original function was doing (see the commented fiddle). Sorry for my ignorance, but even it might be trivial, I can not figure out how to handle your approach with the "multi copy" version,

Comment: @SandorRozsa here is updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/wta4pdpz/15/), as i mentioned before you need to pass customProperties as second parameter after callback function to include the property in cloned object.

Comment: **Excellent!** This is simply perfect! Thank you very much for your  time and efforts... Will drop you also a short mail if you don't mind...